# Exporting repository from xp dev

Tags: git, clone

I seems to have some trouble pulling the repository fro xp-dev.com.  I have git installed and have used the line "git clone https://xp-dev.com/svn/[repo-name]" and after it connects it asks for a login.  After I log in with the username and pw, it gives me the error 
"fatal: repository 'https://xp-dev.com/svn/[repo-name]/' not found".

Why am I receiving this error when I am the owner of the project?  Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: I am typing and receiving these commands in Terminal on mac

Comment: Have you tried accessing that URL through your browser to see if it is there?

Comment: Yes, the repository is there through the URL method.

Comment: I just noticed this is a Subversion Repository, would that make a difference?  Can anyone link me some information about that.

Comment: You need to use [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Comment: Yea I tried git svn clone [link to repo] and it still provided an error